# PHP Prepared statement insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone see anything that is wrong with this. It isn't posting to database at all. There is a basic form asking for name and address on the page. But after submitting the form it just goes to a blank page.

Here is my code. There is stuff above this that reaches out to an API to validate the address data and declares the variables. The dedup part of the code is working in case that matters.

```
if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        // Dedupe the entry into the form 
        $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM formData WHERE (name = '$full_name' AND address = '$primary_number' AND city = '$city_name' AND state = '$state_abbreviation' AND zip = '$zipcode_full' )";
        $duperaw = $mysqli->query($dupesql);
        if($duperaw->num_rows > 0) {
            $dupe .= "$full_name already exists on $primary_number \n";
        } 
        else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO formData(name, address, city, state, zip, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $full_name, $primary_number, $city_name, $state_abbreviation, $zipcode_full, $date);
        $stmt->execute(); 

        header("location: index.php?success=1");
        exit();
        }
    }
```

I have also tried using a query instead of a prepared statement but this just gives the success message and doesnt post to the DB

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO fromData (name, address, city, state, zip, date) VALUES (".
                $full_name . ", " .
                $primary_number . ", " .
                $city_name . ", " .
                $state_abbreviation . ", " .
                $zipcode_full . ", " .
                $date . ")";
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You're only getting a "success" message with the raw query because you're not dying on errors.  Without the quotes around the values, you're almost certain to have broken SQL syntax.

Comment: @cHao i didn't realize that so it is erroring out but skipping the query and going to the header to give the success message? Trying to learn this :)

Comment: Use mysqli_real_escape_string http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php for non numeric values, like Names, etc.

Comment: You seem to be using two table names: `data` and `formData` (and `fromData`...), is that correct or just a typo? By the way, you should add proper error handling to your database calls.

Comment: @Travis: Yes...mysqli doesn't kill the script if a query fails; you need to check for a return value of `false` and handle the error yourself.

Comment: @jeroen that is a typo

Comment: If you don't redirect and echo [`$mysqli->error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php), does it return an error?

Comment: @cHao so much to learn LOL

Comment: @QQQ NO!  Use prepared queries.

Comment: @afuzzyllama it spits out You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Smith, 123 main Ave, Royal Oak, MI, 480673388, 12122013)' at line 1

Comment: @Travis - cHao has answered at least one of the problems with your code :) Happy debugging!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO fromData (name, address, city, state, zip, date) VALUES ('$full_name', '$primary_number', '$city_name', '$state_abbreviation', '$zipcode_full', '$date')";
 $mysqli->query($sql);
```

cHao was hinting towards it

Comment: Dropping prepared statements and opening your site to SQL injection attacks is not a proper fix. What's next? Go back to the deprecated mysql extension and enable register globals?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario if prepared statement is better i would love to use it but i am not sure how to make it work, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @Travis - You are already using them in your code, aren't you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I was trying to but i couldn't get it to work. Then i accepted the other answer because it does work but i don't want to be susceptible to SQL Injection. Do you see anything above with my Prepared Statement that looks off to you?